# enviando state do pai para o filho react native

Tags: react, react-native, react-hooks, native

Preciso modificar o state que esta no componente 'Lancamentos', dentro do componente 'FormBody', que por sua vez, esta dentro do component 'Form' (Lancamentos > Form > FormBody).
Como eu envio meu state para os componentes filhos, inclusive a função do hook.

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
export default function Lancamentos({ navigation, route }) {

    //ESSE STATE EU PRECISO ALTERAR DENTRO DE UM COMPONENTE ANINHADO.
    const [descricao, setDescricao] = useState('');

    return (

        <View>

            <Header descricao={descricao} />
            <Form title="titulo do form" subTitle="Subtitulo do form" />

        </View>

    );

}

export default function Form(props) {
    
    return (

        <View>

            <FormHeader {...props} />
            <FormBody {...props} />

        </View>

    );

}

export default function FormBody(props) {
    
    return (

        //AQUI ONDE O STATE SERA MODIFICADO.
        <View>

            <Text>Descrição</Text>
            <TextInput
                placeholder="Descrição"
                value={???}
                onChange={???}
            />

        </View>

    );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vc precisaria usar contexto ..mas a explicação ficaria muito complexa
então vc pode usar hook direto
crie um arquivo chamado useSuaPage.ts, ele retorna uma função

```
export const useSuaPage = () => {
  const [descricao, setDescricao] = useState('');
 
 return {descricao, setDescricao}

}
```

voce usa essa função nos componentes da seguinte maneira

```
const {descricao, setDescricao} = useSuaPage()
```

ou

```
const {descricao} = useSuaPage()
const {setDescricao} = useSuaPage()
```

isso deve funcionar ....mas estude contexts

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, eu vou testar em seguida informo aqui, e farei isso vou estudar como sugeriu!

Comment: Testes feitos, realmente é possível aplicar essa solução, porém é inviável para formulários maiores, no entanto eu acabei estudando contexts, é exatamente o que eu procurava, com o hook useContext() e um provider, tudo ficou simples e bem organizado, e para o crescimento é super viavel, agradeço mesmo a resposta.

Comment: boa... vai pra cima kkk

Comment: o problema disso é q no final das contas vc precisa importar o usecontext em todos os lugares q for usar ... e tem um macete pra melhorar isso e usar o seu context como hook

Comment: const SeuContext = createContext<SeuContextData>({} as SeuContextData);

export function SeuContext({ children }): JSX.Element {

return (
    <SeuContext.Provider value={{}}>
      {children}
    </SeuContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useCart(): CartContextData {
  const context = useContext(CartContext);

  return context;
}

Comment: tudo isso em unico arquivo ...faz seu context normal e depois no mesmo arquivo exporte o hook nesse formato... assim vc usa o context ...mas o q vc importa onde for é o hook.... no meu github tem exemplo de uso

Comment: da um voto depois ja respota pfv rsrs

Comment: ✌ vlw pela dica!